# How to untar rootfs.tar.gz file faster or with multiple threads using busybox shell

Tags: bash, shell, embedded-linux, busybox

I am untaring rootf.tar.gz in the Embedded Linux board using **busybox sh** shell,
How to make untaring of tar.gz file faster
Currently i am using below option,

```
tar -xzf rootfs.tar.gz
```

Is there a option to make untaring faster, I referred [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/270814/fastest-way-to-extract-tar-gz) link but that doesn't work for me.I referred [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214458/any-linux-command-to-perform-parallel-decompression-of-tar-bz2-file) question on stackoverflow but it didn't help either.

Comment: Are Your performance limited by I/O speed (reed/write from filesystem) or by cpu?

Comment: I have ext4 filesystem, RFS is on eMMC on am335x(armv7). I am not sure what limits my speed. Basically programming script takes 5 minutes to update the firmware I want to speed up the process. so i am looking for optimization.

Comment: Try to have a look on `top` while decompressing and see what's the cpu usage. I don't know am335x, is it a multicore architecture? (If it is not a multi core I think that parallelization is not an option to improve speed)

Comment: So, I think you have no chance to improve performance but trying another faster MMC (if the performance is limited by I/O speed). Look at `top` and see the `%id`  and `%cpu` fields, what do they say?

Answer (score 3):

Extracting a tar.gz won't be any faster on the same hardware. Let's think a bit out of the box.

**Does it have to be compressed?**

You can uncompress the archive beforehand, maybe on the host system

```
gunzip rootfs.tar.gz
```

then untar the uncompressed archive

```
tar xf rootfs.tar
```

thus saving a lot of processor cycles on the embedded board.

**Does it have to be an archive at all?**

Creating lots of small files can be very slow on memory card devices, because they operate with a much larger block size, like 128k. You can accelerate the process by preparing the filesystem image on the **host**, and copying it in one piece.

First, create an empty image file of e.g. 128 MBytes. You should change the size to fit your device.

```
# dd if=/dev/zero of=rootfs.ext4 bs=1M count=128
```

Create a filesystem on the image

```
# mkfs.ext4 -F rootfs.ext4
```

Mount the image

```
# mount rootfs.ext4 /mnt -o loop
```

Extract your rootfs

```
# (cd /mnt/;tar xf /somewhere/rootfs.tar.gz)
```

Don't forget to unmount it afterwards

```
# umount rootfs.ext4
```

Now you can copy `rootfs.ext4` over to the **target** board, and install it on a partition (just make sure it's not mounted, and adjust the device name accordingly)

```
# cat rootfs.ext4 > /dev/mmcblk0p2
```

Comment: Thank you for reply @berendi, one more point, if I want to have journaling I should format `rootfs.ext4` using `mkfs.ext4 -j -F rootfs.ext4`, is my understanding correct ?

Comment: Your welcome. Using ext4 implies journaling, so you don't have to specify it separately.

Comment: Three more questions, though they not related to original question, if you answer, it will help me :) , 1. What if my rootfs size is only 45MB(assuming i have created image with 128MB) will cat copy only 45MB of data or everything else? 2. After copying rootfs.ext4 to /dev/mmcblk0p2, I can apply the lable to it right ? 3. What about filesystem tuning, do I have to do anything for tuning?

Comment: 1. It will copy the entire 128 MB, but it should not take more than 30 sec.
2. You can apply the label as you like, afterwards, or beforehand with the -L option to ext4.
3. It's a complex topic, and depends on your application. It's best to make it readonly, and mount writable directories like `/tmp` on a ramdisk. If you can't make it readonly, be sure to specifty the `relatime` option in `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: I think this one is last question :P my RFS partition size is 200MB, rootfs size is 45 MB so process would go as follows, 1. format `/dev/mmcblk0p2` in ext4 filesystem. 2. cat previously created rootfs.ext4 image to `/dev/mmcblk0p2`. And then memory used on RFS partition would be ~45MB and ~155MB would be free, is it correct ? OR I have to make rootfs.ext4 size same as partition size and then make rootfs.ext4 Image?